# Select specific attribute in element

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a xml database which a few details in it but i am having trouble getting a value of an attribute. I'm using XDocument - linq to xml.

My database:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Bundle xmlns="urn:uiosp-bundle-manifest-2.0" Name="ContactUsPlugin" SymbolicName="ContactUsPlugin" Version="1" InitializedState="Active">
  <Activator Type="ContactUsPlugin.Activator" Policy="Immediate" />
  <Runtime>
    <Assembly Path="bin\ContactUsPlugin.dll" Share="false" />
  </Runtime>

  <Functionality>
    <Controller>About</Controller>
    <View>Index</View>
  </Functionality>

  <Scripts>
    <Script version="1">
      <Location>E:\Git Projects\Kapsters\Plugins\ContactUsPlugin\Sql\Sql1.txt</Location>
    </Script>
    <Script version="2">
      <Location>E:\Git Projects\Kapsters\Plugins\ContactUsPlugin\Sql\Sql1.txt</Location>
    </Script>
  </Scripts>
</Bundle>
```

I'm trying to get the path attribute from the element Assembly.

What i tried:

```
 var assemblyLocation =
            ManifestDocument.Element(ns + "Bundle").Element("Runtime").Element("Assembly").Attribute("Path").Value;

     var assemblyLocation =
            ManifestDocument.Root.Descendants("Runtime").Select(x => x.Element("Assembly").Attribute("Path").Value).First();

    var assemblyLocation =
           (from db in ManifestDocument.Root.Descendants("Runtime") select db.Element("Assembly").Attribute("Path").Value).First();
```

Comment: That's a different question, that was selecting an attribute in the root element. You can't use the same query to get the attribute here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the namespace in the Descendants() method else it would just return null:

```
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("urn:uiosp-bundle-manifest-2.0");
XDocument ManifestDocument = XDocument.Load(@"myxml.xml");

string path;
var assemplyElement = ManifestDocument.Descendants(ns + "Assembly").FirstOrDefault();
if (assemplyElement != null)
{
    path = (string)assemplyElement.Attribute("Path");
}
```